# Rust - How can I return multiple variables from a function such that they are accessible outside the scope the function is called in?

Tags: vector, rust

I want to call a function if a condition is met and return multiple values that will be used outside the scope of the conditional block.  If the function were only to return one value I would declare the variable at an appropriate earlier point, but as far as I can tell Rust does not allow for assignment of multiple variables unless these variables are also being declared.

Is there a way around this?

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate my question:

```
 // This approach doesn't work for scope reasons

fn function(inp1, inp2) {
    calculate results;
    (var_a, var_b, var_c)
}

fn main() {
    
    let state = true;
    
    if state == true {
        let (var_a, var_b, var_c) = function(input_1, input_2);
    }
    
    do something with var_a, var_b, and var_c;
    
}
```

```
// This approach works when returning one variable

fn function(inp1, inp2) {
    calculate results;
    var_a
}

fn main() {

    let var_a;
    
    let state = true;
    
    if state == true {
        var_a = function(input_1, input_2);
    }
    
    do something with var_a;
    
}
```

Comment: Can't you set the previously declared variable to a tuple?

Comment: I can declare a tuple, i.e. 'let (var_a, var_b);' but I haven't been able to assign return values to multiple previously declared variables

Comment: Now that I've read MaxV's answer I can see what you were getting at.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can use that approach to solve it (note commented `if` statement, explained below):

```rust
fn function() -> (i32, i32) {
    return (42, 54);
}

fn main() {
    
    //let state = true;
    
    let v: (i32, i32);
    //if state == true {
    {
        v = function();
    }
    
    let (var_a, var_b) = v;
    println!("a:{} b:{}", var_a, var_b);
    
}
```

If you would like to keep the `if` in place then `else` branch should be provided as well. Otherwise there will be an error like:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly-uninitialized variable: `v`
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 |     let (var_a, var_b) = v;
   |          ^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `v.0`
```

That error don't have any relation with "returning a tuple". The same error come even for the provided 'one variable' example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89ba39e5285304e71a91baf84832e9e0)).

The [final solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3377c4e9e5c6f9269569bbc5538eb09) may looks like:

```rust
fn function() -> (i32, i32) {
    return (42, 54);
}

const DEFAULT: (i32, i32) = (0, 0);

fn main() {
    
    let state = true;
    
    let v: (i32, i32);
    if state == true {
        v = function();
    } else {
        v = DEFAULT;
    }
    
    let (var_a, var_b) = v;
    println!("a:{} b:{}", var_a, var_b);
    
}
```

P.S. I personally prefer to move the `state`'s check inside the `function` to simplify the code.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  Thank you so much.  For the conditional to remain useful in my code I had to use tuple indexing rather than a declaration but you've provided the missing piece.